# Getting a FieldError when trying to populate my models with fake date, python

Tags: python, django

.[When I run my population script using Faker to get fake data for my database i get this error, what is a fix for this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hP8KI.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your question misses a lot of explanations en code examples, the same goes for the image you linked.

What I think the problem is that you model AccessRecord has no field **date**. You should add a field **date** to your **AccessRecord** model or remove the **fake_date** when creating an object.